# Java 8 - Can I use lambda to make sure field is not in list?

Tags: filter, lambda, java-8

How can I convert the following pseudo code into a Java 8 lambda?:

```
...
if(fee.getTaxID() not in (126,127,128))
{
...
```

I'm hoping that by leveraging lambdas I can avoid the following code:

```
...
if(fee.getTaxID() != 126 && fee.getTaxID() != 127 && fee.getTaxID() != 128))
{
...
```

The goal is that I can replace the 126,127,128 in the pseudo code with a List<Integer>

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it using lambda, you can do this:

```
if(IntStream.of(126,127,128).noneMatch(t -> t == fee.getTaxID())) {

}
```

It does not make the code shorter though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without lambdas and java8.

```
List<Integer> badIds = Arrays.asList(126,127,128);
if(!badIds.contains(fee.getTaxID())){
}
```

Or in one line

```
if(!Arrays.asList(126,127,128).contains(fee.getTaxID())){
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I suppose that lambdas couldn't make it any shorter or more concise.